# Sql Server Order By combine two values as one

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have following data table

```
   id - name -  city
 - 1    George  Seattle
 - 2    Sam     Boston
 - 3    John    Los Angeles
 - 4    Amy     Milwaukee 
 - 5    Eric    Chicago
 - 6    Nick    New York
```

here i want to consider chicago and Seattle as same city

so the order i want is

```
   id - name -  city
 - 1    George  Seattle
 - 5    Eric    Chicago
 - 6    Nick    New York
 - 4    Amy     Milwaukee 
 - 3    John    Los Angeles
 - 2    Sam     Boston
```

so what condition i should use when using `order by city Desc`

Comment: What's the logic here? You've given *one* example for us to reason from and even then not explained why/how that example works.

Comment: ORDER BY (CASE WHEN City = 'Chicago' THEN 'Seattle' ELSE City END) DESC

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case when then condition in the order by clause

```
select id,name, city from
yourtable
order by
      (case when city=N'Chicago' then N'Seattle' else city end) desc
```

I'd suggest that if you need to do this often then consider using a mapping table